# Initializing State to Props creates a link

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to keep the props passed in and the state separate but initialize the state to the props.

```
Main.tsx

const [data, setData] = useState([false, false]);

<Random
   sample={data}
/>
```

```
Random.tsx

const [foo, setFoo] = useState(props.sample);

const changeFoo = () => {
   hold = foo
   hold[1] = true
   setFoo(hold) //<-- this also changes the props.sample array (I want to avoid doing that)
}
```

I have tried doing

```
Random.tsx 

const [foo, setFoo] = useState([])
useEffect(() => setFoo(props.sample));
```

But this also creates that link between the foo state and sample props where if I change the state, the props also change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spread operator should do the trick

```
const [foo, setFoo] = useState([...props.sample]);
```

Comment: Please mark you issue as resolved.
Glad to help